# Datalabels is getting hidden outside the svg container in Sunburst Highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

In Sunburst highchart I am showing the data labels outside the circle using x & y positioning.

```
dataLabels: {
  y: -75,
  rotation: 0,
  x: -15
}
```

But if I am giving certain value to x or y axis
(for e.g y:-110) and if the labels goes outside the svg container then it is getting hidden.
Is there any way using css than we can avoid this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akryx2o7/3/

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be resolved in the demo.
I have just added crop: false and overflow: 'allow' in data labels

```
dataLabels: {
        y: -150,
      crop: false,
      overflow: 'allow',
      rotation: 0,
      x: 60,
}
```